# Contrapositive of a Math.ceiling Statement

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

I have the statement:

> If the difference ⌈x⌉ - ⌈y⌉ is negative, then ⌈y⌉ > ⌈x⌉ or both ⌈x⌉ ≤
>   0 and ⌈y⌉ ≤ 0.

Am I right in thinking that the contrapositive would be:

> If ⌈y⌉ > ⌈x⌉ and both ⌈x⌉ ≤ 0 and ⌈y⌉ ≤ 0, then the difference ⌈x⌉ -
>   ⌈y⌉ is not negative.

Thanks.

Comment: Contrapositive in general means that $P\Rightarrow Q \equiv ¬Q\Rightarrow ¬P$ for any two propositions $P,Q$, where $¬P$ denotes NOT P.

Hence the correct contrapositive statement would be

If $\lceil y\rceil \leq \lceil x \rceil$ and both $\lceil y\rceil > 0$  and $\lceil x \rceil > 0$, then the difference $ \lceil x \rceil - \lceil y\rceil $ is not negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite: you're not properly negating the *consequent*. The sentence is a conditional, of the form $p\to q$. In such a sentence, the *antecedent* is p, and the *consequent* is q. The contrapositive is $\neg p\to \neg p$.

In this case, the antecedent is "the difference ⌈x⌉ - ⌈y⌉ is negative", and the consequent is "⌈y⌉ > ⌈x⌉ or both ⌈x⌉ ≤ 0 and ⌈y⌉ ≤ 0".

The consequent $p$ is of the form $r \lor (s\land t)$, where $r$ is "⌈y⌉ > ⌈x⌉", $s$ is "⌈x⌉ ≤ 0", $t$ is "⌈y⌉ ≤ 0". Applying DeMorgan's laws, 
$$\begin{align}
\neg p &\iff \neg(r\lor(s\land t)) \\
&\iff \neg r\land(\neg s \lor \neg t) \\
\end{align}$$ 
which means "⌈y⌉ ≤ ⌈x⌉, and (⌈x⌉ > 0 or ⌈y⌉ > 0)"

So the contrapositive of the statement is:

> If ⌈y⌉ ≤ ⌈x⌉, and either ⌈x⌉ > 0 or ⌈y⌉ > 0, then the difference ⌈x⌉ - ⌈y⌉ is not negative.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know about the inequality signs, I forgot about them.

Comment: He actually goes about trying to prove the statement, in contrapositive form. In his second sentence "In the contrapositive, you assume that the righthand side of the implication is false, and use that to prove the hypothesis true" -- I don't know what "hypothesis" means, really, but it has to mean the negation of the original hypothesis, i.e. $\neg$ antecedent. His perspective is more like proof strategy; I talk about it more from the point of logical equivalence of the two statements, and I pay more attention to the parts of the antecedent — the inequalities which you forgot to negate :)

Comment: True, I just noticed how the proof does in fact make sense. I didn't notice his if lines were meant to be different proof lines. I thought it meant something else.

Comment: Anyway, you got the basic form of the contrapositive right, and you got that "and"s change to "or"s and vice-versa, *but* you neglected to negate the inner atomic statements, the inequalities: "not ≥" is "<", and so on. A few more exercises like this and it'll be second nature.

Answer (score 1):

The implication in the first statement is of the form $p \vee (q \wedge r)$. Thus, its negation is of the form $\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)$. In the contrapositive, you assume that the righthand side of the implication is false, and use that to prove the hypothesis true. The contrapositive should assume $\lceil x \rceil \geq \lceil y \rceil$ and either $\lceil x \rceil >0$ or $\lceil y \rceil >0$.

Proof: Assume $\lceil x \rceil \geq \lceil y \rceil$. If $\lceil x \rceil >0$, then subtracting a lesser amount will result in a nonnegative (in fact, strictly positive value). If $\lceil y \rceil >0$, then $\lceil x \rceil - \lceil y \rceil \geq 0$ since $\lceil x \rceil \geq \lceil y \rceil$.

Comment: My +1 -- a good different perspective on this. As it happens the statement under consideration is true :), and you examine the contrapositive for the proof strategies it offers. One quibble: strictly speaking, in your proof (2nd paragraph) you should probably assume ⌈x⌉≥⌈y⌉ (as you do at the end of the 1st paragraph) and then conclude ⌈x⌉−⌈y⌉ ≥ 0 ("the difference is not negative").

Comment: @BrianO Thank you for the compliment! It's flattering to think that my response can be considered a different perspective while I just feel as though I'm giving a more juvenile argument. And I must admit; I had completely forgotten that the inequality should not be strict until I read your answer above! I fixed it in the first paragraph, but had forgotten about the other paragraph, so thank you for that too.

Comment: You're welcome :)